# How to send custom hello to server

Tags: go, smtp

I try create an SMTP sender in Go. This is part of code:

```
client, err := smtp.NewClient(remote, smtpServer.Host)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer client.Close()

auth := SmtpLoginAuth(smtpServer.Username, smtpServer.Password)
authErr := client.Auth(auth)
if authErr != nil {
    fmt.Println("login error", authErr)
    return authErr
}


client.Mail(data.From())
client.Rcpt(data.To())
bodyWriter, err := client.Data()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("body error", err)
    return err
}
```

My problem is: I want to change hello message for server, in this moment my app send from localhost, i want to send DNS domain of my server but I don't know how I can do this in go.

example place where I want to change localhost string : https://jmp.sh/sugc8Ax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the name used within the EHLO/HELO command can simply be done with `Hello(name)`. From [the documentation](https://godoc.org/net/smtp#Client.Hello):

> func (c *Client) Hello(localName string) error
>   Hello sends a HELO or EHLO to the server as the given host name. Calling this method is only necessary if the **client needs control over the host name used**. The client will introduce itself as "localhost" automatically otherwise. If Hello is called, **it must be called before any of the other methods**.

Thus, all you need to do is something like this:

```
client, err := smtp.NewClient(remote, smtpServer.Host)
...
client.Hello("foobar.example.com")
```